# What's the probability that k + n^2 is squarefree, for fixed k?

Tags: pr.probability, nt.number-theory, probabilistic-number-theory, sums-of-squares

While playing around with [this question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/16780/square-free-sum-of-two-squares) (when is the sum of two squares squarefree?), from some experimental computations (and bolstered by the fact that the density of squarefree positive integers is known to exist), I came up with the following conjecture:  the asymptotic density of squarefree numbers in the sequence $(k+1^2, k+2^2, k+3^2, \ldots)$, for fixed k, exists and depends on k.

To give an example of what I mean, consider numbers of the form $1 + n^2$.   895 of the numbers $1+1^2, 1+2^2, \ldots, 1+1000^2$ are squarefree; 897 of the next thousand are; 895 of the third thousand; 896 of the fourth thousand.  891 of the numbers $1+1000001^2, \ldots, 1+1001000^2$ are squarefree, as are 895 of the numbers $1+2000001^2, \ldots, 1+2001000^2$.   So there seems to be some constant $C_1$, probably between 0.89 and 0.90, such that $1+k^2$ has ``probability'' $C_1$ of being squarefree.  The same thing seems to happen if we replace 1 with other integers, although with other constants.

Are such constants known to exist?  If they are, how can they be computed?

Comment: The constant between 0.89 and 0.90 is $\prod_p (1-2/p^2)$ where the product is over primes congruent to 1 mod 4, which follows from Bjorn Poonen's answer.  The sequence of squarefree numbers of the form $k^2 + 1$ is https://oeis.org/A069987; a comment there evaluates the constant as 0.8948412245...  Apparently this particular case is due to Estermann, 1931; Heath-Brown gave an improved estimate of the error term in 2010, https://arxiv.org/pdf/1010.6217.pdf

Answer (score 30, accepted):

More generally, suppose that $f(x) \in \mathbf{Z}[x]$ has no repeated factors.  For each prime $p$, let $c_p$ be the number of integers $x \in \{0,1,\ldots,p^2-1\}$ satisfying $f(x) \equiv 0 \pmod{p^2}$.  Heuristically, the probability that a random integer $x$ is such that $f(x)$ is not divisible by $p^2$ equals $1-c_p p^{-2}$, and these conditions should be independent by the Chinese remainder theorem, so one would conjecture that the fraction of integers $x$ in $\{1,2,\ldots,N\}$ such that $f(x)$ is squarefree should tend to $\prod_p (1-c_p p^{-2})$, where the product is taken over all primes $p$.  For large $p$, we have $c_p \le \deg f$, so this product converges.

This guess has been proved for $\deg f \le 3$ (the case $\deg f=3$ is a nontrivial result of C. Hooley).  In particular, this answers your question for $f(x)=x^2+k$.  There is no irreducible $f$ of degree $4$ or greater for which the density is known to exist (except in cases when the density is $0$ because some $c_p$ equals $p^2$).  On the other hand, A. Granville proved that the $abc$ conjecture implies that the density exists and equals the predicted value for $f$ of any degree.  For further references and a generalization to multivariable polynomials, see the papers cited in the references below.

C. Hooley, On the power free values of polynomials, *Mathematika* **14** (1967), 21-26.

A. Granville, $ABC$ allows us to count squarefrees, *Internat. Math. Res. Notices* **1998**, no. 19, 991-1009.

B. Poonen, [Squarefree values of multivariable polynomials](http://www-math.mit.edu/%7Epoonen/papers/sqfree.pdf), *Duke Math. J.* **118** (2003), no. 2, 353-373.